# Update array but don't add new items

Tags: php, arrays

So I have two arrays. An old and a new one. I want to update the new array with the variables from the old array but I don't want to add any new indexes that are in the old array that aren't in the new array.

```
$old_array = array("1" => "one", "2" => "two", "3" => "three", "4" => "four");
$new_array = array("1" => "1", "2" => "2", "3" => "3");
```

So I want the new array to be:

```
$updated_array = array("1" => "one", "2" => "two", "3" => "three");
```

Could anyone help me with the most effective way to do this?

Comment: the effective way is array_intersect_key,see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really wanted to give @void-main the correct answer but he made some slight mistakes that I had to fix and he didn't end up updating it. Thank you though, for helping me get started!

```
$old_array = array("1" => "one", "2" => "two", "3" => "three", "4" => "four");
$new_array = array("1" => "1", "2" => "2", "3" => "3");

foreach($new_array as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($old_array[$key]))
        $new_array[$key] = $old_array[$key];
}

//new_array is now the updated array.
```

This way, the new array will still keep all of the values even if they aren't apparent in old_array

Answer (score 2):

Can try using `foreach()`. Example:

```
$old_array = array("1" => "one", "2" => "two", "3" => "three", "4" => "four");
$new_array = array("1" => "1", "2" => "2", "3" => "3");
$updated_array = array();
foreach($new_array as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($old_array[$key])){
        $updated_array[$key] = $old_array[$key];
    }
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($updated_array);
print '</pre>';
```

Comment: what if `$old_array` doesn't have anything from `$new_array`? nothing ends up getting transferred over to `$updated_array`. Also I think you meant `$key` in most of the foreach statement instead of `$val`

Comment: then what you desired?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreach` method (Key Value documentation is provided):
Here's an example from the PHP Docs (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
$result = array_intersect_key($old_array, $new_array);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to update the new array, it just lists the keys that are in both